# How to make div blocks not floating using CSS?

Tags: css, html, css-float, height

**Layout.cshtml**

```
<section id="main">
        <div id="sidebar">
            @{Html.RenderAction("CategoryMenu", "Store");}
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </section>
```

style.css

```
...
    #main {
        padding: 30px 30px 15px 30px;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
        border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #sidebar {
        display: block !important;
        width: 15%;
        float: left;
        font: bold 20px arial, verdana;
        background: green;
        height: inherit !important;
    }

    #content {
        display: block !important;
        float:none;
    }
...
```

I tried to set sidebar's height to 100%, then inherit. What should I do to make two blocks not floating to each other?

Comment: Are looking for `position`? Set `position` to `absolute` or `fixed` and it won't be floating anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidebar is floating left, so it will be taken out of the DOM flow and set up to the left.  If you don't want #content to appear next to it then you need to add clear: both to #content style.  That will force it to clear any floats around it and appear on the next line.  However, it will not stop #sidebar from floating and there will be nothing next to the sidebar.

Can you clarify what you are trying to do since you are specifically setting #sidebar to float:left but then asking how to make them not float.

Comment: How to put two block side by side without floating like this [sidebar][content]

Comment: set them both to display: inline-block; vertical-align: top

Comment: I added inline-block; vertical-align: top to #sidebar and #content. But it is putting #content to the "new line" like this: sidebar then in downside content div

Comment: Typically when that happens it's because they both have widths (possibly margins and padding as well) that together are wider than the parent so the next one wraps down - just like words in a sentence would wrap.  Two ways around this:  1. reduce the widths till they fit 2. set the parent to white-space: nowrap. nowrap will force it to keep them together but it could result in horizontal scrollbars due to the width.

Comment: white-space:nowrap effecting to children divs. About width: how to make two divs width in ratio : 15/85 of parent width

Comment: As @Matt Pillegi suggested, I changed two div block's width 15/85 ratio in order to fit into parent block. Then assigned float: left for sidebar and float:right for content. Working fine: #sidebar {
    display: block !important;
    width: 15%;
    font: bold 20px arial, verdana;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    width:85%;
    float:right;
}